# J2OBJC_HOME not correctly defined in Settings.xcconfig

Tags: ios, xcode, jar, j2objc, j2objc-gradle

I must to include *.jar files in my Xcode project so I decided to use j2objc to translate them into Objective C. I tried to configure my project with no success so I just downloaded a sample project from [here](https://github.com/tomball/j2objc-sample-reversi) and [here](https://github.com/yixiang/Xcode-J2ObjC-Example). All of them cannot compile becouse of the same error

J2OBJC_HOME not correctly defined in Settings.xcconfig, currently set to '../j2objc-dist'
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

looks like I am using the wrong path, this is my Settings.xcconfig

J2OBJC_HOME = ${HOME}/j2objc;

HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${J2OBJC_HOME}/frameworks/JRE.framework/Headers";
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = "${J2OBJC_HOME}/frameworks";

I tried many different paths but no success
My j2objc folder path at this point is :/Users/username/j2objc

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

[J2ObjC is distributed as a zip file](https://github.com/google/j2objc/releases/latest), which you download and unzip into a local directory of your choosing. That local directory plus the release name ("j2objc-" + version) is the J2OBJC_HOME. For example, on my system I have a "/usr/local/tools" directory where I unzipped j2objc-1.3.zip, so my current J2OBJC_HOME is "/usr/local/tools/j2objc-1.3".

In each of the sample projects, J2OBJC_HOME is defined in an xcconfig file. To update the project to work on your system, edit that file and change the J2OBJC_HOME environment variable to wherever it is for your system.

There's nothing special about "J2OBJC_HOME", it's just an environment variable name both sample projects use.